# How to refresh/reload kendo comboBox dataSource with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui, refresh, reload

I do:

```
    .data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.read();
    .data('kendoComboBox').refresh();
```

but comboBox still doesn't reload.

Comment: can you show some more code? 
`element.data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.read();`
`element.data('kendoComboBox').refresh();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted in the comments shows that you are trying to reload the combobox's datasource. This will work if `comboBoxDataSource` is of `kendo.data.DataSource` type. What I woud suggest you is to use the model `$scope.comboBoxListOptions` to control the UI:

```
$scope.comboBoxListOptions.dataSource.read();
```

> There is no need to call refresh() method after dataSource.read().

Check this demo for more details: http://dojo.telerik.com/OfIFo

As a side note, do not use private variables like "_data". It is safer to use the API:

- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data

Answer (score -1):

comboBox.Items.Clear();
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;